# Login to local admin from mobile user

Tags: macos, user-account, active-directory

I'm on MacOS 13.5 on a Macbook. On the first login screen after turning my computer on (which I think it's for FileVault), a local admin user shows up (which I have the password to). I can login here, but then afterwards a new login screen shows up where this user is not there, only my Mobile account (connected to my org's AD).

This user was supposedly hidden some time ago with a command like this:
`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add username`

I can't 'su' into this account or use it whenever an admin prompt shows up from my Mobile account. Any tips? Any way to log into it? Can't even click on "Other" and login from the Login Screen.

The user shows up fine if I run this command from my mobile account:
`dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a new local user in System Settings while being logged in with your Mobile Account?

Comment: I would need admin rights for that. The mobile user doesn't have them, hence why I'm trying to access this local account.

Comment: Not sure whether https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212190 helps in your case.

Comment: This is likely because `su` and `sudo` aren't authenticating to the LDAP/AD Domain.  Basically, to these utilities your mobile account doesn't exist.  Apple gives an overview of [macOS integration with AD](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depd1a7cad1f/web).  To fix this, you might have to involve your IT department to help configure your Mac (`su` and `sudo` authentication settings) along with LDAP/AD authentication (at the server).

Comment: But this would be backwards... I'm on a mobile account and want to su/sudo into a local account.

Comment: `su` and `sudo` use local authentication by default.  Your domain account uses network credentials that get cached.  The key here is your domain account **isn't** using local authentication so, you can't use those utilities with that account.  They will have to authenticate the same way your domain account does - to the LDAP/AD server (and cache the credentials)